# why i am unable to download all json values in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest, uicollectionview

I have backend api it contains all values i can see those values in postman.. but while parsing i am unable to download all values from api.. some times i am getting all values.. some times i am not getting only some values.. if i close app and run again then i am getting all values.. again if i close and run or if i go to other viewcontroller and coming back to home then i am missing some values. if i print `jsonObj` i am not getting all values from api.. why is this happening?

here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage
struct JsonData {
var iconHome: String?
var typeName: String?
var id: String?
init(icon: String, tpe: String, id: String) {
    self.iconHome = icon
    self.typeName = tpe
    self.id = id
}
}
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
var itemsArray = [JsonData]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    homeServiceCall()
    //Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemsArray.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell
    let aData = itemsArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.paymentLabel.text = aData.typeName
    cell.paymentImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:aData.iconHome ?? ""), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "varun finance5_icon"))
    return cell
}
//MARK:- Service-call
func homeServiceCall(){

    let urlStr = "https://dev.com/webservices//getfinancer"
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        guard let respData = data else {
            return
        }
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }
        do{
            let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: respData, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
            print("the home json is \(jsonObj)")
            let financerArray = jsonObj["financer"] as! [[String: Any]]
            for financer in financerArray {
                guard let id = financer["id"] as? String else { break }
                guard let pic = financer["icon"] as? String else { break }
                guard let typeName = financer["tpe"] as? String else { break } //changed this one to optional too. Avoid force-unwrapping. Keep everything safe
                let jsonDataObj = JsonData(icon: pic, tpe: typeName, id: id)
                self.itemsArray.append(jsonDataObj)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("catch error")
        }
    }).resume()
}
}
```

Please help me in the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try network call with background thread.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background).async {
    self.homeServiceCall()            
}
```

And the `URL` is legal with double `/` as below ?

```
let urlStr = "https://dev.com/webservices//getfinancer"
```

And check the all of your backend data's is compatible with your JSONSerialization type of `JsonData` struct.

I hope it helps.

Comment: in my json i have one nil image from that i am not getting remaining ones.. i have checked now why?

Comment: i didn't posted orginal url in my above post.. actually i am getting all values from url to json

Comment: ok, can you share an example of your json? and which parts are working now?

Comment: no. i am getting all values in json.. but i am able to display only first fifteen values in collectionview

Comment: i have nil image in sixteen from that i am not getting any values to display in collectionview

Comment: check your image url's in `cellForItemAt`, its upon to `sd_image` framework. If the url is legal, so it have to fetch all images

Comment: so, image url is nil cause of backend situation?

Comment: yes, only one image url is nil but from that nil value the remaining values are not coming

Comment: so you must check and log `let jsonDataObj = JsonData(icon: pic, tpe: typeName, id: id)` lines, look at the values and if this is valid the problem is in another part of code.

Comment: yes problem solved.    self.itemsArray.append(JsonData(icon: pic ?? "", tpe: typeName, id: id ?? ""))

Comment: so the problem is gone?